# Problema al comparar cadenas de string

Tags: php, string, comparaciones

intento obtener una comparacion entre 2 cadenas totalmente diferentes, y las funciones que he encontrado no me han ayudado, o no las he usado bien.
Intentare explicar el problema:
** La cadena1 se obtiene a partir de recorrer un .txt, por lo que puede variar, pero el formato es siempre igual 
** La cadena2 se obtiene a partir de un archivo existente, solo es el 'numero'.xml 

$cadena1 = "00:02:55 - Se ha creado el archivo 1.xml" 
$cadena2 = "1.xml"

Al intentar comparar estas 2 cadenas no he logrado que la comparacion sea correcta.
lo que se quiere lograr, es saber si, la cadena2, se encuentra dentro de la cadena1.
Esto dado que se estara revisando un archivo en busqueda de su existencia
Si existe, no sucede nada, pero si no existe, se debe crear (esto es a parte solo busco realizar la comparacion)

Hasta ahora no he logrado comparar usando comandos como strcmp o strpos, ademas he intentado con otros como substr_compare, sin resultado satisfactorio.
Dejare un ejemplo:

```
$cmp = fgets($file); <-- Se obtiene la cadena1
    $buscado = "05:00:54 - Se ha creado el archivo 8.xml"; <- este texto existe // cadena2
    $val = strcmp($cmp, $buscado);
    if ($val == 0) {
        echo ("El registro de este archivo existe </br>"); <- Nunca llega a lograr que el texto existe o no
        fclose($file);
        break;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo suelo usar la función strpos(), te dejo la [documentación por aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) para que le eches un ojo (presta atención a los valores que pueden devolver).

Lo que hay que tener en cuenta de esta función es que si la cadena no existe en el texto devuelve **false**, pero de existir, devuelve la posición en el texto y puede que devuelva un valor que se evalúe como **false**, por eso hay que usar el operador "===".

Para tu caso sería así:

```
$cmp = fgets($file);
$buscado = "05:00:54 - Se ha creado el archivo 8.xml";
$pos = strpos($cmp, $buscado);
if ($pos === false) { // No existe la cadena => $buscado no existe en $cmp
    // ...
} else { // Existe la cadena
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias !!!! No entendia del todo el tema sobre que devuelve booleanos, pero ademas un numero que podria ser false, y claro, en este momento esta devolviendo un numero, el cual no es considerado booleano.